Why would rebel factions capturing Aleppo make it safer to return to?
I was reading this Reuters article: https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/rebels-capture-aleppo-stirs-syrian-homecoming-hopes-turkey-2024-12-05/
which claims that

Syrian rebels captured Aleppo from President Bashar al-Assad's forces, bringing hopes of return among hundreds of thousands exiled from the city, which has been under Assad's control since 2016. The rebels said on Thursday they had started a push further south into the city of Hama.

The article further states:

The situation in northwest Syria had stabilised since 2020 under a deal between NATO-member Turkey, which backs the political and armed opposition, and Russia, a key ally of Assad.

I’m finding the context of this confusing, or like I’m missing an important piece of the puzzle.

There are hundreds of thousands of displaced civilians from Aleppo in Turkey
The situation in Aleppo has been stable for nearly half a decade
Aleppo is now once again an active conflict zone

What about this makes it safer for people to return? Won’t this just displace more people? If the situation has been stable for so long, how is the new destabilization good for the displaced persons?

It's hard to answer without knowing the future.  HTS claims it will be chill, but its leader was an ISIS and Al-Qaeda affiliate in the past.  On the other hand, both Europe and Turkey are hosting millions of displaced Syrians who fled the country due to either a) the civil war itself b) Assad's rule in particular or c) the rule of the rebel groups (which included ISIS at some point).  Resolution of the war and removal of Assad, if it gets to that, and IF Syria somehow (shades of dashed Arab Spring hopes) became more livable afterwards -> most refugees choose to return/are returned home.

After Assad's fall certainly there is a massive desire to declare the Syria issue solved EU countries double down on a halt to Syrian asylum claims but will not yet send people back.  Which again seems a bit premature, at this point.

If you watch the rebel (propaganda) videos, many fighters now/later based in Idlib were originally from Aleppo. And they are happy to be reunited with their (more or less distant) families in Aleppo. So, there's at least that return angle. Here's BBC article about those, without the videos.

Abdulkafi, an English teacher from Aleppo, saw his father for the first time in years on Monday, days after rebels launched a major offensive and took control of the northern Syrian city from government forces.
“He is 85, an old man. He never dreamed he would see me again before he died,” said Abdulkafi, who lives in opposition territory. Until the offensive he had been unable to cross into regime-held Aleppo.
A video of the encounter, seen by the BBC, shows the two men embracing and sobbing with emotion.

"hundreds of thousands exiled from the city" -- presumably this refers to IDPs etc., which fled rather than chose to live under Assad after he retook the whole of the city, around 2016. Before 2016 the city was for years split along government and opposition lines of control. I don't know if the numbers of displaced from the city are correct as it's hard to find any confirmation on that level of granularity.
I see

Turkish Interior Minister Ali Yerlikaya has said more than 40% of 3 million Syrians in Turkey are from Aleppo, once the country's biggest city.

If there's no mistranslation that would imply some 1.2 million Aleppo residents fled and are currently in Turkey. I find that rather implausible in relation to Wikipedia's demographic history of Aleppo...

Most likely he's selling some bridge to a domestic audience there. Syrian refugees having become a very contentious topic in Turkey's domestic politics. Perhaps he means from the broader Aleppo Governorate, which had a pre-war population of 4-5 million. Turkey's interior ministry also announced this summer that some 625K Syrians had voluntarily returned to the Turkish controlled 'safe zone' in Syria (then containing the cities of Jarabulus, Al-Bab, and Azaz--the largest of these has a population of about 60K). But human rights NGOs have disputed the voluntary nature of many of these returns.


Aleppo is now once again an active conflict zone

Well, the city was taken with surprisingly little fighting in 2024. To the surprise of many, Assad's forces mostly fled. But you're right to question how safe it is for now, because it was reportedly hit by Russian air strikes once again, including on its hospitals. (This was a common tactic during the 2016 government offensive that then retook the city. Ibid.)
There is hope however that with the heavy fighting now around Hama and Homs, which are quite further south, pro-Assad forces will have little resources left to spend on bombing Aleppo much. The bombing of Aleppo has been less intense in 2024 compared to 2016.

There's another angle on which the rebel taking of Aleppo might be less than rosy, but you haven't mentioned it. It's ethnically and religiously quite a mixed city. Thus far there's been no reported large exodus from the city (particularly of Shia), but the Turkish-backed militias have reportedly been targeting the Kurds in the city. However, if they flee, they most likely won't flee to Turkey.  When SNA took Tel Rifaat during this offensive, many Kurds (perhaps as many as 100K) fled to other Kurdish-controlled areas around Raqqa and Tabqa. (Sources from Arabic countries are eager to point out that Arabs also fled that area when the SDF took over the region from ISIS.)
HTS leadership (on which Turkey has less direct control) has been emitting a message of toleration of minorities in the past few days. Whether that will hold out on ground or if we'll see Taliban-style progressive oppression remains to be seen. (Some HRW observers are skeptical.)

As I understand it, Aleppo was considered to be a prominent region of rebellion against Assad's regime, and so the regime's forces occupied it to root out and suppress rebellious and subversive elements. Counter-insurgancy operations of that sort present a clear risk to civilian populations, because:

suspected insurgents and their friends and families may be targeted
by regime military units
regime forces cannot easily or systematically distinguish combatants
from non-combatants in urban environments, and so regime attacks
are often indifferent to collateral damage
crackdowns and fighting disrupt supply chains, transportation routes,
businesses, and other necessities, making daily life difficult at best

The key is to remember that 'stability' does not necessarily imply 'safety' or 'ease'. When the Assad regime took control of the city, many people thought it wise to flee, fearing any or all of the above possibilities. Now that the regime forces are gone, most of these existential threats are removed, and people are likely to return to pick up their lives as best they can.
To (possibly) make it clearer: imagine that the city or town you live in was suddenly flooded with heavily armed police, guardsman, or soldiers tasked with finding rebels or insurgents. Imagine it becomes a common experience to be stopped by someone with a machine gun demanding to know who you are, where you're going, and what you're doing. Imagine that the sound of firefights and explosions is a near daily occurrence. It seems to me that anyone with a brain (and enough resources) would start thinking about an extended vacation elsewhere, and be inclined to stay elsewhere until all those government agents have left or been driven out.

I don't see how long would you expect that to persist as years pass, and why that won't be repeated once again when Syrian government sympathizers are targeted instead.

@alamar: There's a difference between potential danger and clear and present danger. In most places in the world police and military are a potential danger, but most people ignore them because the risks are comparatively low. I mean, right now it's perfectly conceivable that police get their wires crossed and storm your house looking for a drug lab that isn't there, guns blazing. You and your family could die, but it isn't something you'd expect.

@alamar: But if police started doing that in your area regularly and systematically, acting as though everyone is suspected of having a drug lab, I suspect you'd get out of town. That danger is clear and present, not remote.

@alamar: And generally speaking, insurgents aren't oppressive in that way. They expect the oppression of the governing regime will bring citizen's to the insurgency's side; they worry more about infiltration into their ranks than about dangers from random citizens; they have enough to do keeping out of the government's line-of-fire.  They may become oppressive if they eventually win, but that just means that they have become the government.

They are government now. Let's suppose some people were not brought to the insurgency's side - what happens to them now? Why you would think rebels won't do just that. Let's suppose they never win big, but also keep control of Aleppo, and not everybody is happy with their (internationally illigitimate) rule.

@alamar: If the insurgents win and become the government, things mainly depend on how they rule. Generally speaking, only the worst forms of authoritarian regime go down the secret police, death squad route, and that only after there are significant challenges to their rule. Assad didn't crack down on Aleppo until there was open rebellion, right? Most governments tolerate a decent amount of grumbling and disaffection mainly because it's too time and resource intensive to track down and deal with minor dissidence. And if the insurgence go democratic, they won't worry about dissent much at all.

@alamar: But in the new government starts act as bad as the old government, and decides to occupy Aleppo to deal with the supporters of the old regime, well… likely you'll see a new wave of refugees who escape the city until the new oppressive government is kicked out.

That's what I expect to happen here.

@alamar: I understand that fear, but we can't let it get the better of us.

Looks like Asad is gone for good, which makes the expectations better for Syrian Arabs, provided a single rebel faction is able to hold power in their area.
